# How to pass Navigator function as a parameter in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I have a custom widget which represents a button and this widget is in a separated folder called "Widgets" inside the "lib" folder, and that is the button widget file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Widget buttonWidget(String text, Function action) {
  return ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () => action,
    child: Text(text, style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
  );
}
```

now in the main.dart file I want the buttonWidget to use the Navigator.pushNamed function, so I called the buttonWidget like the

```
buttonWidget("Navigate", Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/screenTwo')),
```

but the buttonWidget call gives me this error

```
The argument type 'Future<Object?>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Function'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an anonymous function surrounding the call, just as you would if you were directly passing it to the `onPressed` parameter.

```dart
buttonWidget("Navigate", () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/screenTwo')),
```

or

```dart
buttonWidget("Navigate", () {
  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/screenTwo');
}),
```